# TCP ACK ignored, retransmission SYN ACK, why?

Tags: tcp

We don't understand this TCP behavior showing that a redhat linux 5 TCP stack (HTTP server, this is where this dump is from) received an ACK for a SYN,ACK but continues ignoring that and repeats duplicated SYN, ACK 5 times. Finally the server sends a RST for a HTTP GET on this 'connection'.

```
Time                          Source                Destination           Port   Protocol Length Info
2015-01-30 08:42:18.387260000 81.74.146.89          124.219.82.236        80     TCP      74     64866 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=8 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=988669132 TSecr=0
2015-01-30 08:42:18.387309000 124.219.82.236        81.74.146.89          64866  TCP      62     http > 64866 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1
2015-01-30 08:42:18.387354000 81.74.146.89          124.219.82.236        80     TCP      60     64866 > http [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0
2015-01-30 08:42:21.386871000 124.219.82.236        81.74.146.89          64866  TCP      62     [TCP Retransmission] http > 64866 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1
2015-01-30 08:42:21.387118000 81.74.146.89          124.219.82.236        80     TCP      66     [TCP Dup ACK 3#1] 64866 > http [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 SLE=0 SRE=1
2015-01-30 08:42:27.386919000 124.219.82.236        81.74.146.89          64866  TCP      62     [TCP Retransmission] http > 64866 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1
2015-01-30 08:42:27.387165000 81.74.146.89          124.219.82.236        80     TCP      66     [TCP Dup ACK 3#2] 64866 > http [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 SLE=0 SRE=1
2015-01-30 08:42:39.387130000 124.219.82.236        81.74.146.89          64866  TCP      62     [TCP Retransmission] http > 64866 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1
2015-01-30 08:42:39.387376000 81.74.146.89          124.219.82.236        80     TCP      66     [TCP Dup ACK 3#3] 64866 > http [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 SLE=0 SRE=1
2015-01-30 08:43:03.387486000 124.219.82.236        81.74.146.89          64866  TCP      62     [TCP Retransmission] http > 64866 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1
2015-01-30 08:43:03.387709000 81.74.146.89          124.219.82.236        80     TCP      66     [TCP Dup ACK 3#4] 64866 > http [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 SLE=0 SRE=1
2015-01-30 08:43:51.588227000 124.219.82.236        81.74.146.89          64866  TCP      62     [TCP Retransmission] http > 64866 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1
2015-01-30 08:43:51.588449000 81.74.146.89          124.219.82.236        80     TCP      66     [TCP Dup ACK 3#5] 64866 > http [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 SLE=0 SRE=1
2015-01-30 08:57:13.679727000 81.74.146.89          124.219.82.236        80     TCP      353    64866 > http [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=299
2015-01-30 08:57:13.679740000 124.219.82.236        81.74.146.89          64866  TCP      54     http > 64866 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F2ZO.png

pcap:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ave4sctozc5m2a4/TcpAckIgnored.pcapng?dl=0

What is the reason for this TCP Spurious Retransmission? Are there ways to analyze this? Any help is deeply appreciated.

Thomas

Comment: How certain are you that the ACK is actually getting to the stack?  Is the sniffer running on the host itself?  Is it possible that you have an IPTables FW rule that is preventing the ACK from being handed up?

Comment: Yes the sniffer is running on the same host. The behavior is not stable. It does only happen sometimes. I saw sometimes only 2 retransmissions and in most cases it works flawlessly between those addresses. I should add, there is a remote syslog tool installed.

Comment: Try running the sniffer with '-vv' and verify that the checksums are valid in the returning ACKs.  It is possible that the embedded protocol checksum is being corrupted somewhere.  This will still allow it to route but the receiving host will drop it silently.  This would indicate that there's a network device between here and there that's corrupting stuff intermittently.

Comment: The checksums of IP header and TCP are OK. netstat -i reveals no dropped packets. Iptables -L -v reveals no dropped packets as well.

Comment: Keyword: `TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT`. A more in-depth analysis: https://labs.ripe.net/Members/gih/the-curious-case-of-the-crooked-tcp-handshake

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation we came to the conclusion that this is an apache behavior we can reproduce any time with:

"telnet serveraddress 80"

If we start a simple webserver with "nc -l 80" there is no retransmittion.

So the apache needs at least a TCP PSH or any datapacket to open the connection. You can monitor that with netstat.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on a reloading database, so I found this question. But it looks like we are in different reason, so I will post my result here and other people who reach this problem can see here.

In my case, if I have a listening port and you can't accept the new comming connection fast enough, you will get this retransmission problem when the listen queue is full. I have test code below, you can use it to test by yourself. I've tested it on a ubuntu12.04, I am not sure if you will get the same behaviour or not on other linux version.

[Test code](https://gist.github.com/johnzeng/70e0a2d2aad1205bab6e29073e1dce68)

BTW, the apache behaviour might be related with TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT, it's referred in this question: [real-world-use-of-tcp-defer-accept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94104/real-world-use-of-tcp-defer-accept)

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me, and I found that the subnet mask of the target host was misconfigured (24 instead of 16).